Toggling the visibility of rows on a large table is very slow
I have an HTML table generated with a <asp:GridView/> object via a VB.NET call that populates the table from a database query.
The result is a table like this:
<table id="myTab">
<tr><td>val1</td></tr>
<tr><td>val2</td></tr>
.
.
<tr><td>valN</td></tr>

The JavaScript code is on a button:
function toggleHide(val) {
   tb = getElementById("myTab");
   if ( tb != null ) {
      trows = tb.rows;
      for ( var i = 0; i< trows.length; i++ ) {
         if ( trows[i].cells[0].innertText == val ) {
            trows[i].style.display = 'none';
         }
         else {
            trows[i].style.display = '';
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}

This works well with smaller volumes of data, but once we get over 100, it simply stops processing/crashes, leaving the page blank.
I get it that accessing the DOM repeatedly like this might be slow. Is there an alternative faster way?

I don't think should happen.  What about the data you're fetching?

The initial page load showing all the data is fine. Executing the code to hide certain values using Javascript hangs when the table has over 100 rows.

innerText is slower then textContent. Instead of using for loops you could use forEach and instead of your if/else-statement you could improve times by toggling a class using classList.toggle('d-none', statement)

How many different valX can there be? Is that somehow limited, or could the cells contain practically anything? If it is limited, you might want to add classes based on the values to the table rows themselves, and then hide whichever ones currently need to be hidden, via a CSS rule ...

@C3roe valX is indeed limited to a handful of values. So maybe a combination of your advice and that of tacoshy will work.

@ProWest I tested your code and got an error with getElementById. It works when using document.getElementById. The execution time of the function then varies between 10-20ms for 10,000 rows. Can you post a working [repro] so I can debug there?

@tacoshy Thank you, that's interesting. The page/table is dynamically generated in a APSX web app as a GridView item, and runs on IIS. The pages  contains business data so I cannot post. The actual table though has 13 columns, and the valX is column 12. I do not know if that makes a difference.  But once the page is fully rendered, the javascript should only run the client right? Could you post your sample test code as an answer below and I can try to see if I get the same response?

@ProTest here: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/WNVoNpR?editors=1111 - I even tested it with 100k rows. I dont expect you to post business data but an reproducable example that shows the issue. So far none of us was able to reproduce the high excution times.

Are you sure the issue is with the JavaScript code? From your description and from the JavaScript code you have shown, it sounds like the issue might be your VB.NET code.

@TylerH I've copied the VB/ASP generated page to a simple HTML file and am experimenting with the code locally. I get the same issue with performance.

Someone has seen fit to close the question. That's harsh because even from the responses I was able to get some ideas on resolving this problem. Clearly if people have been able to provide hints and answers, they've understood the question. And they docked me the +1 I got as well!!

@Yogi . There was sufficient information in the question to allow at least 3 kind souls to provide relevant and helpful answers. That should be a criteria. Plus the issues I have is a head scratcher, meaning it is a problem that is unusual and may be of technical interest.

@Yogi I see. So now we are require to test all code posted in questions.  I am actually doing this as part of my job, where I cannot copy and paste code into this web app so have to key code in by hand. But nonetheless, people with sense were able to understand the question, it's context and provide useful hints and answers, which are helping me get to the bottom of this. I bet as well those who responded will be interested in learning what the solution is. But I'm minded now not to bother posting that.

While others may have been able to give suggestions, a [mre] is crucial because the pieces that are left out could be the key to solving the puzzle.

@mykaf The fact that some people are able to provide answers with the information provided should in itself be a consideration towards the 'worthiness' of a question.

@tacoshy Simply changing the loop to forEach, using textContent and also querySelectorAll suggested by other fixed the issue. Now it runs very quickly. Thanks again. +10

If the values inside the cells are known before-hand, and limited, @C3roe's comment is the best solution.
Otherwise, if you're looking for something dynamic for any text, try this:

Add the cell's contents as a data-attribute for the row during content generation.
Add a dynamic style to the page to hide the cells containing the given text:

'tr[data-txt*="'+txt+'"]{ display: none; }'
Full example and related fiddle for 10.000 rows. Try it out with any size you want:
function initDemoData(limit=1000){
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var thetable=document.createElement('table');
    for (var i=0;i<limit;i++){
        var tr=document.createElement('tr');
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        var txt = ((i%2==0)?"some text ":"other ")+i;
        tr.setAttribute('data-txt',txt);
        td.innerText=txt;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        thetable.appendChild(tr);
    }
    fragment.appendChild(thetable);
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(fragment);
}

function searchHandler(){
  if (window.searchTimeout){
    window.clearTimeout(window.searchTimeout);
  }
  window.searchTimeout=window.setTimeout(function(){    //to avoid rapid filtering as you type
    var txt = document.getElementById('filterTxt').value;
    var stylesheet=document.getElementById('dynamicStyle');
    if (stylesheet){
        stylesheet.remove();
    }
    stylesheet=document.createElement('style');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('id','dynamicStyle');
    stylesheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode('tr[data-txt*="'+txt+'"]{ display: none; }'));  //E[foo*=something] Element where foo attribute CONTAINS something
    document.body.appendChild(stylesheet);
  },500);
}

document.getElementById('filterTxt').addEventListener('input',searchHandler);
initDemoData(10000);  //do your tests by changing this value


The jsFiddle crashes my browser (Chrome, latest), sorry

I think I need to figure out now how to set the CSS class for each row from the VB that assigns the datatable to the gridview.

Edit For a lot of rows the performance price may still be pretty high. If you really need speed, apply the handling to a clone of the table (so only in memory) and when done replace the original table with the clone. I've conconcted an example here.
It shouldn't be that slow. I suspect that every button click iterates through all rows of the table. This is not very efficient.
First: you can use event delegation to make handling more efficient.
Second: use a css class for the hiding.
Third: try limiting the number of iterations through the rows to a minimum (e.g. by using querySelectorAll and more precize css selectors).
Here's an example for a few scenario's with the aformentioned in mind.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
createDemoTable();

function handle(evt) {
  const rowClicked = evt.target.closest(`tr`);
  const hideByValue = evt.target.dataset.value;
  
  // hide with explicit cell value
  if (hideByValue) {
    const allRows = document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr:not(.hidden) td`);
    // Array.find iterates until found, so may be more efficient
    const cellFound = [...allRows]
      .find(cell => cell.textContent === hideByValue);
      
    if (cellFound) {
      const row = cellFound.closest(`tr`);
      row.scrollIntoView();
      row.classList.add(`hidden`);
    }
    
    return;
  }
  
  // hide by clicking on a row
  if (rowClicked) {
    return rowClicked.classList.add(`hidden`);
  }
  
  // hide even rows
  if (evt.target.id === `hideEven`) {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr`);
    return rows.forEach((row, i) => 
      row.classList[(i + 1) % 2 === 0 ? `add` : `remove`](`hidden`)
    );
  }
  
  // hide odd rows
  if (evt.target.id === `hideOdd`) {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr`);
    return rows.forEach((row, i) => 
      row.classList[(i + 1) % 2 !== 0 ? `add` : `remove`](`hidden`)
    );
  }
  
  // show all
  if (evt.target.id === `showAll`) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`#myTable tr.hidden`)
      .forEach(row => row.classList.remove(`hidden`) );
  }
  
}

function createDemoTable() {
  const table = Object.assign(
    document.createElement(`table`), 
    {id: `myTable`} );

  for (let i=0; i<500; i+=1) {
    const row = Object.assign(document.createElement(`tr`));
    row.append( 
      Object.assign(document.createElement(`td`), 
      {textContent: `row ${i+1}`}) );
    table.append(row);
  }
  
  document.body.append(table);
}
#myTable {
  tr.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  tr:hover:after {
    content: 'remove this row';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  }
}
<button id="hideEven">Hide even rows</button>
<button id="hideOdd">Hide odd rows</button>
<button id="showAll">Show all rows</button>
<button data-value="row 42">Hide "row 42"</button>
<button data-value="row 499">Hide "row 499"</button>




I am finding that querySelectorAll has made a difference but over 1,000s of rows it is still slow. Other things that make a difference are reducing the number of columns. But there is a fundamental slowness on my browser. I will let you know if the CSS approach works.

FYI Simply changing the loop to forEach, using textContent and also querySelectorAll suggested by other fixed the issue. Now it runs very quickly. Thanks again.

You could use querySelectorAll() to get all the table rows first this will reduce your calls to DOM and make your code a lot faster.


function toggleHide(val) {
    var tb = document.getElementById("myTab");
    if (tb !== null) {
        var trows = tb.querySelectorAll('tr');  // Use querySelectorAll to select all rows at once
        var rowCount = trows.length;
        
        // Cache the table rows to avoid repeated DOM access
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var rowText = trows[i].cells[0].innerText || trows[i].cells[0].textContent;  // Get text content, handling both innerText and textContent
            
            // Check if the row matches the value we want to hide or show
            if (rowText === val) {
                trows[i].style.display = 'none';  // Hide matching row
            } else {
                trows[i].style.display = '';  // Show all other rows
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}




Thank you. This made a difference, but unfortunately not enough to solve the problem.
